# Enabling the EA events only when required

Tags: enterprise-architect

We have used an EA Event EA_OnPostNewDiagram Event which is triggered for the creation of new diagram.But I want this event to be called only during specific condition not for all diagram creation .So how can enable or disable this EA events. can we use this API Repository.EnableEventFlags to  enable or disable EA events or what is the purpose of this API Repository.EnableEventFlags

Answer (score 1):

You can not turn it off since there is neither an unsubscribe nor a flag in EA. Just have your own flag and simply return from your add-in in case the flag is set.